# Is there, in typescript, a way to define a type in which the type is every possible combination of a subset of strings?

Tags: typescript, string

Let's say we have the following types:

```
type DNA = {
    G: string;
    C: string;
    T: string;
    A: string;
}

type DNAKeys = keyof DNA;
```

Is it possible to define a type such that we define every possible combination of string literals that are composed of `DNAKeys` into a flat string type?

This problem gives me a lot of language syntax definition vibes, and I mostly was curious if it was even possible with current Typescript.

The test scenario would be as follows:

```
let dna: DNA = {
    G: 'C',
    C: 'G',
    T: 'A',
    A: 'U'
}

const doSomethingWithDNA = (dnaString: DNACombinations) => {
    for(const letter of dnaString){
        console.log(dna[letter]);
    }
}
```

The only possible thing I can think of is to manually sit there and define an ever increasing dictionary of combinations like this:

```
type DNACombinations = 
    | DNAKey
    | `${DNAKey}${DNAKey}`
    | `${DNAKey}${DNAKey}${DNAKey}`
    // ad infinitum
```

Alternatively, like actual syntax checks, this might be something that has to wait until regex types are a thing?

Comment: Does using `type DNACombinations = Partial<DNA>` works to you? This makes every prop of your type an optional prop so you can use any combination you want

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript/43053803#43053803  you're after a cartesean product

Comment: Without regex types or something like them this is impossible.  The closest you can get is a generic constraint that *checks* a string literal, and even this doesn't understand that `letter` is a `DNAKey`.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mqy0dm).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz makes sense, maybe one day the answer to this question will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without true regular expression validated types as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#41160](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160), what you are trying to do is impossible.  There is no specific type `DNACombinations` corresponding to strings that consist only of the characters `"A"`, `"C"`, `"G"`, and `"T"`.

The closest you can currently get is to make a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `ValidDNACombinations<T>` that acts like a [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on `T`, so that `T extends ValidDNACombinations<T>` if and only if `T` would have been assignable to your desired `DNACombinations` type.  Here's one way to write that:

```
type ValidDNACombinations<T extends string, A extends string = ""> =
    T extends `${infer F}${infer R}` ?
    F extends DNAKeys ? ValidDNACombinations<R, `${A}${F}`> : `${A}${DNAKeys}` :
    A;
```

That's a [tail-recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) which uses [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to parse `T` into individual characters, checking each one in turn against `DNAKeys`.  If every character matches then the output will just be the same as the input.  Otherwise the output will be the longest initial segment of the input that matches, plus a final `DNAKeys` character at the end.  So a bad input will result in a good output which is "close" to it, to hopefully provide helpful error messages.

Then you could write `const v: ValidDNACombinations<"CAT"> = "CAT"`, but that's redundant.  So we can make a helper function `asDNACombinations` that *infers* the type argument for you.  Like this:

```
const asDNACombinations = <T extends string>(
    t: T extends ValidDNACombinations<T> ? T : ValidDNACombinations<T>
) => t;
```

That's a bit complicated because TypeScript balks at a more straightforward recursive constraint like `<T extends ValidDNACombinations<T>>(t: T) => t`.  Anyway let's test it out:

```
const okay = asDNACombinations("GATTACA");

const bad = asDNACombinations("ATTACKING"); // error
// Argument of type '"ATTACKING"' is not assignable to parameter of type
// '"ATTACA" | "ATTACG" | "ATTACC" | "ATTACT"'.
```

So the good input is accepted, while the bad input is rejected with an error message that shows the problem.

---

Note that this still doesn't give you the desired behavior whereby splitting the string into characters is known to produce an array of `DNAKey` values. The compiler is unable to perform the higher-order reasoning to know this.  I'm not even sure if this would even be possible with regex types.  So you'll need a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or the like to tell the compiler about that:

```
const doSomethingWithDNA = <T extends string>(
    dnaString: T extends ValidDNACombinations<T> ? T : ValidDNACombinations<T>) => {
    for (const letter of dnaString) {
        console.log(dna[letter as DNAKeys]); // <-- assertion needed
    }
}
```

But at least it works from the caller's side:

```
doSomethingWithDNA("CAT"); // okay
doSomethingWithDNA("DOG"); // error
```

---

One final note, and this is mentioned in [a write-up in microsoft/TypeScript#41160](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41160#issuecomment-1503653578): these sorts of things only really help if your data is *static*, in the form of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) known at compile time, so your TypeScript code looks like `doSomethingWithDNA("CAT")` where the `"CAT"` string literal is in the code directly.  If, on the other hand, your data is *dynamic* and never appears directly in the TypeScript code, so your TypeScript code looks like `doSomethingWithDNA(getDNAFromSomewhere())`, where `getDNAFromSomewhere()` returns a value of type `DNACombinations` but not a string literal type, then it's really not very useful at all.  You might as well just give `DNACombinations` a nominal-ish type like the following [branded type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal):

```
type DNACombinations = string & { __validDNA: true } & Iterable<DNAKeys>;
declare function getDNAFromSomewhere(): DNACombinations;
```

Then your `doSomethingWithDNA` implementation works well enough even without an assertion (because I said that it was `Iterable<DNAKeys>`):

```
const doSomethingWithDNA = (dnaString: DNACombinations) => {
    for (const letter of dnaString) {
        console.log(dna[letter]); // okay
    }
}
```

And then as long as you don't care about hardcoded string literals, you'll be happy:

```
doSomethingWithDNA(getDNAFromSomewhere()) // okay

doSomethingWithDNA("CAT"); // error, but who cares, you won't do this
```

This doesn't require regex types or generics or anything, and you can do it today.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAIgcgQSgXigbwFBW1A4gLigGdgAnASwDsBzAbixwGFCSKb6coAVFsquhtgS82AgL4YMAGwjAoAE0oBDQvCSpMnAlADkjHQBpBUZrtyHjPXQgudhugKo6ME0JFiIA0hBBEUUAGsfAHsAMw8Eegw3aAA1JSlyeTVGYIBbACMqJWByYMoiAB4uKAgAD2AISnk-Vn4DKCRyyuravhp-ACJOgD4US1KKqpqoAAMAEjQqUIhSKAAxMUnp2agAJTFRqAB+Y3nBlpG1b18dqHjE5MRUzOzc-KK1hom0BCW0RdG+whe3yeOfERNlB8MZIpIAMYPORKIgpdJZZT3Ar+YoHYZtUQ9AAUxmAhBKzQx5wSSXhtyReQKxT6224IJJl3JiJyVKKXB6GAAlCg+sAolCCnJggElCB-LDmXc2djOrgEFwuAhGAhOlz6IKSFAMkp5BK4dcEdKHrKFUrGJ4AJJwXBq2hQAD0DtKpFIwVIGCdjVI1AArmkqsLwjFdJ0zcqrTbOjooOQ-JRgjCiERyNRlBkZFBgMEoGAlKQlAHKnMwlnwNAdGHFcrVVAAD5QKvm231xvhxiMTqtpvKrjRgB0kgwmrk8mCAGV0rIABb8ADq5GA07UqMJQ1axHa1BxxkUSnHW4J6I3FzJhoprIeNLOJUIp6uyqNlKvHJ5yD6mhwoXdUGxI6gMjAMWUClnuB6iDyn6cNgmrBDI-ZSME1DYnuADagHAbCEQnEQAC66qOs6hQALTEVms5+LCRCzMisZtOQUhSFAlAQBA8hscYEgSBgY6TkWs40AuS5qLKKp9gRXoimKPETlOS7zouy6ILKMAAPK2hJzqzG6HoYMoAZEHmELQHA6TZExmB4uWEQ3CyyJ+KgdQdAAZOgUAAPruQAbqSD6EGQvrQGIUCuZaxZKBmECFACvg9BwODsRCUj5tAoS+pQEK0dQshqPMbppHxEAAO7TrMEDYlyqjnnZbLxTB0IKLJ-EKcJiD+ChyjgfwVWPhe9lvh+xicN+cx-g1GGrKBnVbpBQ3QfVBRwRACFIR1SjobIxb4fakmiiAc3YBInBHQlTUzi1SkINi2XALl+WFSVZUVTyu3SZwvFyQJ1BCZdokKnahEujpLhAA)